# android SQLite - manage a single database with multiple users

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating an app which allows a user to login and retrieve some information about his account from a server. These information are inserted in a SQLite database, and then the user can set other preferences on them (I use sharedpreferences for this).

Now i want to expand the app allowing more users to login.
The problem is that i don't know exactly how to manage the database with multiple users, infact:

- if I keep db after logout, and login with another account, I find the information related to the previous user;
- if I don't keep the db, and erase it after logout, I miss all the preferences set by the user;

How can I solve this problem? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in multiple ways
1. Have user id table created and link that to other tables using foreign key.
another way is
2. create new DB for each of the users. so your database name will have username. If user name changes then database changes.

with second way your code changes will be minimal.

Comment: the first way is the one i have thinked to! Maybe the second is easier but if there are too much account it can be more heavy for the app, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Well second way, you will have to make sure that you make clean switch in DB and in the app ( which has data picked from DB) once user logs out and login back again. First way is clean but it requires serious look at the DB design also you will have to take care of the app upgrade as well since DB design is changing

Comment: I was thinking to this: and if I save the additional preferences (which I save through SharedPreferences) in a file (for example xml) before the user logs out and then, at the next login by him, i retrieve them searching by username and password?